# Gradle Multi-module project : Beans are not getting scanned from other modules

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-injection, autowired, multi-module

```
Parent module
   -- module 1
   -- module2 (SpringBootApplication class resides here)
   -- common module (Declared an interface ABC.java)
```

All my packages starts with com.xxx (in all modules) which I mentioned in scanBasePackages as below.

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xxx"} ...

I have beans in both module 1 and module 2 implementing interface ABC.java

**Problem :**

Beans inside module1 is not getting scanned.

when I try to autowire ABC.java (interface) only Beans from module 2 is getting injected.
module1 beans are not getting injected.

I checked several solutions where they suggested to have common basePackage which in my case have no problem with that.

Note : Similar project in maven is working fine

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to your common module in the corresponding grade file `implementation project(':common')`. Check example here https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-gradle-multi-module/